# Resolving a Graphql query from different data sources

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server, typegraphql

I have a graphql server I've created using ApolloServer and Type-Graphql.

I have two types defined on my graphql server:

```
User{
   id:string;
   name:string
   email:string;
   ...
}

UserPrefrences{
   userId:string;
   theme: string;
   color:string;
   ...
}
```

The data for the `User` type is saved in a database which I access through a different graphql server by forwarding the request I get from client.

The data for the `UserPrefrences` type is saved on a different database which I access directly from my graphql server.

I don't want my client side to need to know these two separate types and to need to run two separate queries.
I'm looking for a way to let my client run the following query on my graphql server:

```
query UserData($userId: String!) {
   id
   name
   email
   theme
   color
}
```

But if I forward this request to the graphql server that I'm querying, I will get a response saying the fields 'theme' and 'color' are unknown to him.

I'm trying to find a way to forward only the relevant fields to the graphql server, and then resolving the rest within my graphql server. But I receive the query as a string which makes it a pain trying to use regex to only forward the fields I'm interested in.

I'd be more than happy for any ideas on how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

the only way I found is using a Graphql client in Node.js.

I'm using the npm library called **graphql-request**
https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-request

```
import { GraphQLClient, gql } from 'graphql-request';

const client = new GraphQLClient('http://localhost:4000/graphql');

const query = `
  {
    yourQuery {
      id
      name
    }
  }
`;

const response = client.request(query);
```

Comment: or if in a async/await add await:
const response = await client.request(query);